# 500 years after a nuclear holocaust, a boy searches for a door

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I read a book years ago that early on explains about a nuclear holocaust that took place 500 years before the story. There is mention of "giants", large areas turned to glass, and other areas that are "poisoned" (radiation). The main protagonist of the book was a boy around 18 years old who had grown up in what I think was an aboriginal tribe.

Part way through the book, some people from the past that have been in cryogenic stasis wake up as a result of a malfunction.

Comment: There is something about a door in the title of your question, but nothing about the door in your question.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect that this might be Terry Carr's *[Ozymandias](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82346/scavengers-dance-their-way-to-pyramid-to-avoid-magic-defenses/82348#82348)*. It involves a post-holocaust world and a tribe raiding a building from the past replete with traps. They wake up part of humanity, who are giants compared to the current people. A young boy is the main character.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be *[The Einstein Intersection](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/145354.The_Einstein_Intersection)* by Samuel R Delany. It's ringing just enough bells with me, but I can't quite be sure.

> The surface story tells of the problems a member of an alien race, Lo Lobey, has assimilating the mythology of earth, where his kind have settled among the leftover artifacts of humanity. The deeper tale concerns, however, the way those who are 'different' must deal with the dominant cultural ideology. The tale follows Lobey's mythic quest for his lost love, Friza. In luminous and hallucinated language, it explores what new myths might emerge from the detritus of the human world as those who are 'different' try to seize history and the day.

Comment: We've just discussed The Einstein Intersection in the book group I go to. It's a fantastic book, but it doesn't match the description given by the OP.

Comment: Oh, OK. I must be thinking of something else, then.