# Post Apocalyptic Stasis Chamber

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic, cryostasis

Looking for the name of a short story about small creatures going into a forbidden building looking for artifacts/treasures (multicolored wiring, etc.).  A "dance" is required to avoid security lasers.  They inadvertently wake up a "giant" in cryogenic sleep at the end of the story and kill it (a human).  The small creatures proudly display their treasure to each other.

Answer (score 10):

"[Ozymandias](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42246)" by Terry Carr as per [Scavengers dance their way to pyramid to avoid "magic" defenses](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82346/scavengers-dance-their-way-to-pyramid-to-avoid-magic-defenses/82348#82348). It can be read in *The Light at the End of the Universe*, [available to check out from Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/lightatendofuniv0000carr/page/94/mode/2up).

> Sooleyrah… was the best dancer among them. No approach to the vaults could be made in just the same way.

....

> Sometimes a raid would get through the Immortals’ defenses, and sometimes it would mean danger and death, but it had nothing to with the dance or the rituals.
>
> Lasten’s people had been thinkers, the ones who kept the old knowledge, or what remained of it. They knew that vaults were guarded not by curses or demons… but they were all the same, only defenses left to guard the vaults.

....

> And at last there were only his screams in the vault. The monster, the Immortal, the inhuman giant lay silent and destroyed at his feet.

....

> He held up the fistful of many-colored wires. "Pretty?"

Comment: Also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85836/500-years-after-a-nuclear-holocaust-a-boy-searches-for-a-door?noredirect=1&lq=1, although that's also an unaccepted answer.